# FileOutputStream crashes with "open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)" error when downloading image

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to download an iamge from the internet, Here is the code:

```
try {
                String imgURL = c.imgURL;
                String imgPATH = c.imgPATH;
                URL url = new URL(imgURL);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                try {
                    File f = new File(imgPATH);
                    f.mkdirs();

                    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(imgPATH), 8192); // CRASH HERE

                    byte data[] = new byte[8192];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count = 0;
                    int updateUILimiter = 0;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;

                        if (updateUILimiter == 20)
                            // publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                            updateUILimiter = 0;
                        else
                            updateUILimiter++;

                        output.write(data, 0, count);

                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            output.flush();
                            output.close();
                            input.close();
                            return null;
                        }

                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    c.imgPATH = "";
                    return null;
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                c.imgPATH = "";
                return null;
            }
```

Here is the error message:

> /mnt/sdcard/tmp/3.png: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Why is this?

" /mnt/sdcard/tmp/" exists.

Comment: Because 3.png is a directory?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`3.png` is a directory, because you make it so by calling `f.mkdirs();`. Try `f.getParentFile().mkdirs()` instead. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()):

> Creates the directory *named by this abstract pathname*, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

(emphasis mine). In other words, the entire path contained in the `File` instance `f` is taken to be a directory name, up to and including the final part (`3.png` in the example output).

Comment: @MrLore: this is not equivalent. In particular, it does not make sure, that the intended target directory exists. Also, it may be intentional, that the code overwrites existing files (a case, where `createNewFile` would fail)

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that you are using the function

```
f.mkdirs();
```

this function will create a folder called "3.png" instead of a file called "3.png", so delete this folder first,

[image]

then replace the function

```
f.mkdirs();
```

to

```
f.createNewFile();
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 5):

replace `f.mkdirs()` with `f.createNewFile().`

Answer (score 2):

### You can first make the directory and then further write the code.

```
 URL downloadURL=null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
    try {
        downloadURL=new URL(url);
        urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
        inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/myAppImages/");
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        File file1=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/myAppImages/"+uri.getLastPathSegment());
        fos=new FileOutputStream(file1);
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];

        int read=-1;
        while((read=inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1)
        {
           /* Message.L(""+read);*/
            fos.write(buffer,0,read);
        }

    }
```

#### Like this you can do

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/myAppImages/");
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        File file1=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/myAppImages/"+uri.getLastPathSegment());
        fos=new FileOutputStream(file1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter with this problem when     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
was not written correctly, so check manifest again.