# open Faild EISDIR (Is a Directory) .. how to fix this?

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

Everytime it gives me "unable to decode stream java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open Faild EISDIR (Is a Directory)

how I can get rid of this error .. this class was working fine in many tasks I've done !!

here's the class i'm using to get bitmaps

```
private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

        InputStream iStream=null;
        String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("image");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imgUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // Getting Caching directory
            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

            // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");

            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

            // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

            // Flush the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.flush();

           //Close the FileOutputStream
           fOutStream.close();

            // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("photo",tmpFile.getPath());
            Log.d("photopah", tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position",position);

            // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
            return hmBitmap;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Try using the two parameter version of creating a file-  File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory, "wpta_"+position+".png");  This will create a file inside the directory in the first parameter.  Also, check your filesystem and make sure you didn't somehow make some directories there by accident.

Comment: I tried but it gave me same error

Answer (score 5):

You properly needs to call:

```
tmpFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

before you create the FileOutputStream.

See more: [FileOutputStream crashes with "open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)" error when downloading image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339673/fileoutputstream-crashes-with-open-failed-eisdir-is-a-directory-error-when)